# Inner join on query not working

Tags: mysql, database

I have a fairly large query and the courier part of it is making it not work I am not to sure why, no errors appear but maybe I'm not seeing something...

```
SELECT o.purchaseNo, o.dateCreated, c.Name, m.mouldName, cr.courierName
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN orderedProducts AS op ON op.productID = p.productID
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON op.orderID = o.orderID
INNER JOIN Couriers AS cr ON cr.couriersID = o.couriersID
INNER JOIN customers AS c ON c.customerID = o.customerID
INNER JOIN Moulds AS m ON m.mouldID = p.mouldID
WHERE c.Name LIKE  '%john%'
OR p.name LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Name LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.POC1 LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.POC2 LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Address1 LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Address2 LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Suburb LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.State LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Phone LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Email LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.ABN LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Fax LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.CompanyName LIKE  '%john%'
OR o.purchaseNo LIKE  '%john%'
OR o.dateCreated LIKE  '%john%'
OR cr.courierName like '%john%'
```

the Couriers cr is the line that is causing problems. If I remove it along with any references to cr it works just fine. Otherwise it doesn't.

Any ideas on what may cause this?

I am basically creating a search query. To check against many tables in the database. If you have any advise on how I can make this better as well, that would be nice :)

Comment: john is just being used as a place holder while I test the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a LEFT OUTER JOIN on couriers cr I  guess.

```
SELECT o.purchaseNo, o.dateCreated, c.Name, m.mouldName, cr.courierName
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN orderedProducts AS op ON op.productID = p.productID
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON op.orderID = o.orderID
INNER JOIN customers AS c ON c.customerID = o.customerID
INNER JOIN Moulds AS m ON m.mouldID = p.mouldID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Couriers AS cr ON cr.couriersID = o.couriersID
WHERE c.Name LIKE  '%john%'
OR p.name LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Name LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.POC1 LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.POC2 LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Address1 LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Address2 LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Suburb LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.State LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Phone LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Email LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.ABN LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.Fax LIKE  '%john%'
OR c.CompanyName LIKE  '%john%'
OR o.purchaseNo LIKE  '%john%'
OR o.dateCreated LIKE  '%john%'
OR cr.courierName like '%john%'
```

**The reason behind my guess:**
The resultset appears if you remove the Couriers. So you did not found a match on  `cr.couriersID = o.couriersID`, still as you want the resultset despite of match or no-match you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

[***For more, see Pictorial representation on JOINs.***](http://learnsqltips.blogspot.in/2012/05/pictorial-representation-of-join-in-sql.html)

Comment: Oh wow that did it. Can you explain exactly what that does? Like why do I need it for it and not the others?

Comment: if you always need o.purchaseNo, o.dateCreated, c.Name, m.mouldName, cr.courierName FROM "products" you need to LEFT OUTER for all.